# Validate if jtable is empty?

Tags: java, validation, jtable

I need to know how to check if there is data in a `JTable` something like

```
if(jTextField1.getText().isEmpty()):
    then (if jTable1.isEmpty())
        ...
```

how I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I validate if the jtable is empty with 
    this code.

```
private int calculate() {
    Vector<Integer> myvector = new Vector();

    TableModel mode = new DefaultTableModel();
    mode = jTable2.getModel();
    int n = mode.getRowCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (mode.getValueAt(i, 3) != null) {

            myvector.add((Integer) mode.getValueAt(i, 3));
        }
    }
    return myvector.size();
}

//then I validate with a button
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int numofvalidrows;
    numofvalidrows = calculate();

    if (numofvalidrows == 0) //if the size of the vector is 0 then the jtable is empty
    {
        System.out.println("You need to add people to the jtable, because the table is empty");
    } else {
        // I get the values of the jtable with 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (model.getValueAt(i, 3) != null) {  //whith this "if" I print only data, not print null of the empty cells in jtable
                System.out.print(model.getValueAt(i, 3)) 

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are reassigning mode with what you get from jTable2, i don't think that's correct, where do you load the data? Follow my example, it should be easier.

Answer (score 1):

JTables are not simple components like the jtextfield, like other swing components they have an underlying Data Model, check this example from the javadoc:

```
  TableModel dataModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
      public int getColumnCount() { return 10; }
      public int getRowCount() { return 10;}
      public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { return new Integer(row*col); }
  };
  JTable table = new JTable(dataModel);
```

Like in every UI object that follows the MVC pattern, you don't use the graphical component to understand the values it has, you use the data model. In you case, save a reference to the Data Model of the JTable you created and call `getRowCount` to know how much data you have previously loaded.

Also, check the official docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html).

Comment: 1+ for differentiating between the model and the view. However, the code probably should use the getRowCount() method of the table and check for 0. It is possible that the table could be filtered, in which case the view will give the number of records being displayed in the table.

Comment: Thank you uraimo , reading a reading i had an idea. I wrote the code below